# how to use google maps islocationonedge for servers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to use a function from the google maps api  from the server side (using node.js) 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#poly
I want to see if a point is in the google maps directions for going between point A to point B.

```
isLocationOnEdge(point:LatLng, poly:Polygon|Polyline, tolerance?:number)
```

I used the example code on the google maps documentation, and added a console.log statement. however, it isn't outputting anything to the console.

```
function initialize() {
   var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 5,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886, -70.269),
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

var cascadiaFault = new google.maps.Polyline({
   paths: [
     new google.maps.LatLng(49.95, -128.1),
     new google.maps.LatLng(46.26, -126.3),
     new google.maps.LatLng(40.3, -125.4)
   ]
 });

 var myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(43.0, -125.9, 10e-7);
   console.log('google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(myPosition, cascadiaFault))');
```

}

another stack overflow question said to use include this url in the http request
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE but i know i need to actually include the islocationonedge parameters somehow. 
should i be requesting 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE&islocationonedge(point:latlong, polyline: [adfasd,sdfs,adfasdf,adfasd], 0.0001) ?

thank you very much for your help

Comment: Can you make it work on the client?

Comment: I cannot, it says that google is not defined.

Comment: Then you don't have the library included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this way:

- check https://www.npmjs.org/package/googlemaps (moshen/node-googlemaps)
- read this code https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps/blob/master/lib/googlemaps.js
- f.e. there is function createEncodedPolyline(points) {..}
- step by step try to recreate request to Google Geometry Library

Comment: how do i create requests to the google geometry library though ?